# textbox only accept number when first radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have four radio button, i want when user click first radio button, input textbox can only accept number but if they select other radio button, number and text only can be accepted. Below is my code :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="usr_matriculation" maxlength="40" name="usr_matriculation" required="required">

    <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" onclick="il.Form.showSubForm('subform_usr_id_type_1', 'usr_id_type', null);" name="usr_id_type" id="usr_id_type_1" value="1">
        New Identity Card No.</label>

    </div>


    <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" onclick="il.Form.showSubForm('subform_usr_id_type_2', 'usr_id_type', null);" name="usr_id_type" id="usr_id_type_2" value="2">
        Passport No.</label>

    </div>


    <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" onclick="il.Form.showSubForm('subform_usr_id_type_3', 'usr_id_type', null);" name="usr_id_type" id="usr_id_type_3" value="3">
        Army No.</label>

    </div>


    <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" onclick="il.Form.showSubForm('subform_usr_id_type_4', 'usr_id_type', null);" name="usr_id_type" id="usr_id_type_4" value="4">
        Police No.</label>

    </div>
```

i try use below code but when i select other radio button, i cannot type text need to put number only. do i need to put if else? i need it auto change without refresh the page.

```
$('#usr_id_type_1').click(function() {
      alert("1");

    $('input[name="usr_matriculation"]').keyup(function(e)
                                    {
      if (/\D/g.test(this.value))
      {
        // Filter non-digits from input value.
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      }
    });
    });
```

my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/designblog4u/yock8zdw/

Comment: Just remove the listener when the others are clicked. http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: does it work with radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best solution but I've made some tests.

```
<input type="text" id="i">

<input checked type="radio" id="r_n" name="rn">
<input type="radio" id="r" name="rn">
<input type="radio" id="r" name="rn">
<input type="radio" id="r" name="rn">
```

This piece of code could help you to get to the right way or to improve your own code.

```
$("#i").keyup(function () {
  if ($('#r_n').is(':checked')) {
  console.log("Validating #r1...")
  // Filter non-digits from input value.
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
}
else {
  console.log("Validating the other radios")
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g, '');
}
});
// Optional: Delete input value when radio changes
$('input:radio[name="rn"]').change(
function(){
  $("#i").val('');
});
```

Comment: thank you, i just want to ask one thing, how to remove all text if they input in the textbox before click the radio button?

Comment: You can implement it with an "onfocus" or an "onclick" event to handle it.
`$("#i").click(
    function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });`

Answer (score 0):

When you click the first button that it add an event look for `keyup` of the `$('input[name="usr_matriculation"]')`, so every time you can not type text need to put number only.

Comment: I've thought it too but it looks like there is another issue while changing the radio options.